# Compare two data frames with different rows using R

Tags: r

I have two data frames with different row numbers:

```
class1<-c(1,2,5,6,7)
abund1<-c(10.4,7.5,7.1,5.1,3.2)
df1<-data.frame(class1,abund1)

class2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
abund2<-c(9.5,8.4,8,6.3,6,2.4,1.2)
df2<-data.frame(class2,abund2)
```

I would like to compare these two data frames but I would need the same number of rows. My purpose is to fill by zero all those classes which do not match with the df2. The solution would be as it follows:

```
  class abund
     1   10.4
     2    7.5
     3    0.0
     4    0.0
     5    7.1
     6    5.1
     7    3.2
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use the merge function but I don't know how to fill the empty classes by 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kk<-merge(df1,df2,by.x="class1",by.y="class2",all.y=TRUE)[-3]
kk[is.na(kk$abund1),2]<-0
> kk
  class1 abund1
1      1   10.4
2      2    7.5
3      3    0.0
4      4    0.0
5      5    7.1
6      6    5.1
7      7    3.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and rigth answer @user227710!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df1, key='class1')[df2][is.na(abund1), abund1:=0][, abund2:=NULL][]
 #   class1 abund1
 #1:      1   10.4
 #2:      2    7.5
 #3:      3    0.0
 #4:      4    0.0
 #5:      5    7.1
 #6:      6    5.1
 #7:      7    3.2
```